# How to build a data catalog in Glue for Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue-data-catalog, snowflake-pipe

I am new to snowflake. I am wondering how to build a data catalog for snowflake's data?

I cannot find documentation on that. I can find this [post](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Use-AWS-Glue-With-Snowflake). But it seems that it does not use the catalog function.

Answer (score 0):

I find useful information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/populate-data-catalog.html) where you need to add jdbc connection then define a [crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) but seems not supporting Snowflake database as the latter link says

Crawlers can crawl the following data stores through a JDBC connection:

> Amazon Redshift
>
> Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS)
>
> Amazon Aurora
>
> Microsoft SQL Server
>
> MySQL
>
> Oracle
>
> PostgreSQL

Publicly accessible databases

> Aurora
>
> Microsoft SQL Server
>
> MySQL
>
> Oracle
>
> PostgreSQL

Also, again I find in defining connection link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-defining.html) those are the supported databases only

> AWS Glue can connect to the following data stores through a JDBC
> connection:
>
> Amazon Redshift
>
> Amazon Aurora
>
> Microsoft SQL Server
>
> MySQL
>
> Oracle
>
> PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Now the Snowflake support is added in AWS Glue Crawler.

Refer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/announcing-aws-glue-crawler-support-for-snowflake/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).